# my admob ad small and I can't click it

Tags: android, admob

I'm so confused I do not know why my ad small and I can't click it !
here is two links the first one is my ad the second is another ad I want my ad be the same size and clickable 
I tried so much to do that but I did not get it
http://imageshack.us/f/13/6o0t.jpg/
http://imageshack.us/f/547/s8l3.jpg/

here is my xml :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_add_newDevices"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#22222222"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/f"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/moreapps1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/moreapps" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/show1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/show" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"    
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="id"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/final_about"
android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this two ads tested in same device

Comment: Try changing the adSize to BANNER maybe?

Comment: I tried before , it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe you should post your complete layout?

Comment: do you have the test mode on? Since you can get banned from AdMob for clicking you own ads

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView has android:layout_height="fill_parent".

I'm just guessing, but I think that means it fills the whole page, which might mean it overlaps your ad. If your ad is under your ListView, then it will not be clickable.

You could try replacing the ad with a button, if that one isn't clickable either that would show that my guess is correct.